# How do I distribute a survey questionnaire to obtain a reasonable response rate?

Tags: email, survey-research

I have built a survey questionnaire focused on Software Engineering Researchers and now I need to distribute it, but I am not so sure how. My questions are:

1. Are there any other means to distribute it **to obtain a reasonable response rate while bearing in mind the survey population**?
2. Is it ok to use a electronic mailing list for it? (Regarding both the survey integrity and the mailing list protocols)
3. If so, are there any appropriate mailing lists to my field?

I have recently subscribed to [SBC's mailing list](https://www.sbc.org.br/forun2) and I got used to receiving questionnaires through it. I have done some research and only found [ACM's SIGSOFT](https://www.sigsoft.org/resources/seworld.html).

Editions made to solve any misunderstandings are in **bold**

Comment: What will you do with the results of the questionnaire?  Be sure your procedure is approved in advance by the appropriate authority (such as a university committee) since this constitutes an "experiment with human subjects".  It may sound crazy, but this is required  nowadays.

Comment: Contact SBC and get them to send it out.

Comment: Sending surveys to mailing lists like that sounds like a great way to annoy your entire field (but you say you've been getting them, so maybe it's ok).

Comment: I have the sense that this is the $64,000 question throughout the social sciences.  Welcome to their world.

Answer (score 1):

The University you are affiliated with likely has a 'behavioural research ethics board' or some similar title as was pointed out by @GEdgar. Such surveys constitute behavioural research and require approval by an ethics committee. The ethics application will usually require that you provide information about how participant anonymity will be maintained (YES -- even if that's a 'given'), how/where you will store the data and for how long, and what you will do with the data. The application, in most cases, can be completed online. If you are not the PI, bring your PI in the loop and get them on board. If applicable, you will LIKELY -- not necessarily -- need them to 'sponsor' your endeavour.

**Edit**

It is okay once 'ethics' says it's okay, which it likely will. This is minimal risk behavioural research that will likely see a quick turn around time. Also, the ethics application will require that you share with them the survey you are distributing. As you likely know, if you are using Qualtrics (or equivalent), it should be straightforward to download the questionnaire/survey. Search "YOUR INSTITUTION" AND "ETHICS" on Google. No doubt, you will find the right contacts, and I'm sure they'd be delighted to provide you with additional information, such as sample applications.

Comment: In thinking about anonymity, consider the following: For several years, I was the only female computer science PhD student over age 50 at UCSD. A series of apparently harmless demographic questions would identify me.

Comment: I will definitely take into consideration your advice and look more into the ethics issue. But my question was more directed to how one distributes their survey to obtain a reasonable response rate while bearing in mind the survey population.

Comment: @unelunatriste What Speleo didn't quite say is that in submitting the application (which let me be clear, is *required*), you will have to say how you're gong to distribute it. When you look up their guidelines, they may have restrictions you need to look into.

Comment: @unelunatriste You are correct, I primarily addressed your second question. The reason for this is that how, where, and to whom you will be able to distribute the survey in order to get a 'reasonable' response rate depends on what the ethics will approve. An email list for your field sounds like a great idea. We don't have much other context to go on, in terms of suggesting other methods of distribution that would be practical for you. Are you a student, professor, are you a member of any scholarly associations in your field, etc.? Also, define reasonable response rate for your purpose.